# What is an approximation algorithm in the context of NP completeness in general

Tags: approximation-algorithms, np

In theorem 4 of [Approximability of Minimum-weight Cycle Covers](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0609103) Bodo Manthey proves that:

> *Then **no approximation algorithm**
> for $\operatorname{Min-L-DCC}$ achieves an approximation ratio of $o(n)$, where n is the number of
> vertices of the input graph.*
> ...
> *Thus, **no recursive algorithm** can achieve an approximation ratio of
> $o(n)$*

**Questions:**

- is my conclusion right that there is general definition of approximation algorithms in the context of $NP$ completeness and that these algorithms are certain recursive algorithms that construct the solution for a problem with $n$ vertices from solutions for subsets of smaller size?
- Where can I find an exact definition of that class of approximation algorithms?

Comment: Min-LDCC is an optimization problem, a class of problems for which there is indeed a rigorous and general definition of approximation algorithm. NP is a class of decision problems, but there is a defn of "NP optimization problem" (where an associated decision problem is in NP). Vazirani's textbook Approximation Algorithms should have it.